# Looping through a list of dataframes and saving individual graphs for each

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

Novice coder here. I am working on a script that generates distinct graphs of individuals' moods ratings over a one year period. So far, I can pull the data for one person (ID) and create their respective graph (script below), but this impractical to do manually for a large pool of people. I need a way to loop this script through the list and save individual graphs for each person. I have tried using lapply, but I am unsure how to get it to include all these steps and keep running into errors (e.g. object 'Week' not found). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
ALIFE_transpose_split = split(ALIFE_transposed, ALIFE_transposed$ID)

#Loop would start here, pulling 1038 as an example

ALIFE_1038 <- ALIFE_transpose_split[["1038"]]

ALIFE_1038_plot <- ALIFE_1038 %>%
  select(Week, MDD_PSR, GAD_PSR, ADHD_PSR) %>%
  gather(key = "Module", value = "PSR", -Week)

ggplot(ALIFE_1038_plot, aes(x = Week, y = PSR)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Module, linetype = Module)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow4", "blue", "darkred")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","twodash", "solid")) +
  ylim(1, 6)

ggsave(
  filename="ALIFE_1038_plot_20210122.png",
  plot = last_plot(),
  device = NULL,
  path = "../..",
  scale = 1,
  width = 13,
  height = 8,
  units = c("in"),
  dpi = 300,
  limitsize = TRUE,
)
```

Link to output:
[ALIFE_1038_plot_20210122.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl7xj.png)

This is what I have tried and the error returned:

```
ALIFE_transpose_split <- lapply(ALIFE_transpose_split, function(x) x %>%
         select(Week, MDD_PSR, GAD_PSR, ADHD_PSR) %>%
         gather(key = "Module", value = "PSR", -Week) )

plotdata <- function(x) {
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = Week, y = PSR)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Module, linetype = Module)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow4", "blue", "darkred")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","twodash", "solid")) +
  ylim(1, 6)

ggsave(
  filename=ALIFE_transpose_split$ID,
  plot = last_plot(),
  device = NULL,
  path = "../..",
  scale = 1,
  width = 13,
  height = 8,
  units = c("in"),
  dpi = 300,
  limitsize = TRUE,
) 
}

lapply(ALIFE_transpose_split, plotdata)



Error: `device` must be NULL, a string or a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. 
7.
stop(fallback) 
6.
signal_abort(cnd) 
5.
abort("`device` must be NULL, a string or a function.") 
4.
plot_dev(device, filename, dpi = dpi) 
3.
ggsave(filename = ALIFE_transpose_split$ID, plot = last_plot(), 
    device = NULL, path = "../..", scale = 1, width = 13, height = 8, 
    units = c("in"), dpi = 300, limitsize = TRUE, ) 
2.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
1.
lapply(ALIFE_transpose_split, plotdata)
```

This is what the list data looks like:

```
> dput(ALIFE_transpose_split)
list(`1027` = structure(list(ID = c(1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
1027, 1027, 1027, 1027), Week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64), MDD_PSR = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ADHD_PSR = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), GAD_PSR = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), `1038` = structure(list(
    ID = c(1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
    1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038), Week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
    22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
    37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64), MDD_PSR = c(NA, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ADHD_PSR = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), GAD_PSR = c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -64L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")))
```

Comment: Welcome, it would be good if you could specifically show some of your data using dput() and some of your attempts at solving the problem with the errors these attempt generate.

Comment: Without seeing your data, the source of your problem is likely the non-standard evaluation employed in the tidyverse. if you try to address a column in ggplot (or other tidyverse functions) with a character vector, you need to employ the .data[[]] pronoun. See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more info.

Comment: @MarioNiepel, sure... what would be most helpful? Would showing dput(ALIFE_1038) work or should I include more? I will rerun some of what I have tried and post it.

Comment: I would include data for two people so you can show what does and does not work when you try to use lapply.

Comment: @MarioNiepel I hope the info I provided is helpful. Let me know if I am unclear anywhere. – Stephen J. Suss Chacón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you facet_wrap?

Creating df from your data...

```
ID <- c(1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
        1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
        1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
       1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 
        1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027, 1027)
Week = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
        26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
        42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 
        58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64)
MDD_PSR = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
ADHD_PSR = c(NA,   NA, NA, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
             2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
             NA, NA, NA, NA)
GAD_PSR = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) 

b <- data.frame(ID,Week, MDD_PSR,ADHD_PSR,GAD_PSR)                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
ID <- c(1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 
       1038, 1038, 1038, 1038, 1038)
Week <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
        37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
        52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64)
MDD_PSR <- c(NA,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
             1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
              NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA) 
ADHD_PSR <- c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
              1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
              1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
              NA, NA, NA, NA)
GAD_PSR <- c(NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
           1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
           2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
c <- data.frame(ID,Week, MDD_PSR,ADHD_PSR,GAD_PSR)

f <- rbind.data.frame(b,c)
```

Getting the graphs to show up next to each other

```
c_plot <- f %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  gather(key = "Module", value = "PSR", -Week, -ID)

  ggplot(data = c_plot , aes(x = Week, y = PSR)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = Module, linetype = Module)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow4", "blue", "darkred")) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","twodash", "solid")) +
    ylim(1, 6)+
    facet_wrap(.~ID)
```

Alternatively...This gets the error out of your code

```
c_plot <- f %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  gather(key = "Module", value = "PSR", -Week, -ID)
  
  
  ALIFE_transpose_split = split(c_plot, c_plot$ID)

plotdata <- function(x) {
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = Week, y = PSR)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = Module, linetype = Module)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("yellow4", "blue", "darkred")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","twodash", "solid")) +
  ylim(1, 6)

ggsave(
  filename="figure%03d.pdf",
  plot = last_plot(),
  device = "pdf",
  path = "./",
  scale = 1,
  width = 13,
  height = 8,
  dpi = 300,
  units = c("in"),
  limitsize = TRUE) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I cannot get your first solution to work, but made progress with the second one. The function formed with no errors, but when I try to run the actually. Can you expand on what you mean by this "c_plot"? To clarify, my goal here is to create individual plots for each person, though a long sheet with each might work too

Comment: c_plot was just the name of the data. You can call it whatever you want. facet wrap or grid helps you create individual plots for each person all in one page. What happens when you try running the code?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Well I think the issue is that I can't through the first 3 lines of code. I am substituting "c_plot" with "ALIFE_transposed" and I get "Error in group_by(., ID) : object 'f' not found".

Comment: Remove the group by Id. You probably removed it earlier.

Comment: Got it! This is great. I got your first solution to work perfectly, although it is a bit unpractical with the 50 people we have, this is a great tool moving forward. I have had progress with your second solution now. There are just two things 1) it seems to keep overwriting the first graph (i.e. figure001.pdf) 2) it would be great if I could name the pdf with with ID. I'm running "lapply(ALIFE_transpose_split, plotdata)" at the end of your code.